# ArcPy parameters not being accepted by class constructor

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

This may sound like a general coding question, but the error seems particular to ArcPy and not core python, so I'm cautiously asking it here.

I've got a class called `WFSQuery` that I'm using to do some simple pulls from a WFS service and put it into a more ArcGIS-friendly structure. The `__init__` method takes a base URL and assembles the payload from anywhere from 0 - many user-provided CQL filter parameters expressed as **kwargs:

wfs_query.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class WFSQuery:
"""
Sets up a WFS query (currently only 1.0.0) and obtains a GeoJSON result.
"""

def __init__(self, base_url, **kwargs):
    """WFS query constructor"""

    self.base_url = base_url
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.user_cql = []  # this holds the list of user-provided filters

    if 'sdate' in self.kwargs:
        sdate = f"temporal%20%3E%20%27{self.kwargs['sdate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}%27"  # temporal > 'value'
        self.user_cql.append(sdate)
    else:
        sdate = f"temporal%20%3E%20%27{(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}%27"
        self.user_cql.append(sdate)
    if 'edate' in self.kwargs:
        edate = f"temporal%20%3C%20%27{self.kwargs['edate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}%27"  # temporal < 'value'
        self.user_cql.append(edate)
    else:
        edate = f"temporal%20%3C%20%27{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}%27"
        self.user_cql.append(edate)
    if 'new' in self.kwargs:
        if len(self.kwargs['new']) > 0:  # check if empty string
            another = f"new%20LIKE%20%27{self.kwargs['new']}%25%27"  # another LIKE 'value%'
            self.user_cql.append(another)

    self.url = self.base_url[0] + str("%20AND%20".join(self.user_cql))
```

When I run this using manually set parameters in the following way to mimic what would happen in ArcGIS Pro, it **executes without error**:

scratch.py

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import os
import wfs_query as wq

def get_url():
    json_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'config/urls.json')
try:
    with open(json_file) as f:
        config_json = json.load(f)
        return config_json['server']
except IOError:
    arcpy.AddError(f"Config file {json_file} not found.")
except ValueError:
    arcpy.AddError(f"Config file {json_file} is not valid json.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set environment variables
    # current_project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
    # current_db = current_project.defaultGeodatabase

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Parameters
#input_type = arcpy.GetParameter(0)  # Choice of file or service call
#input_file = arcpy.GetParameter(1)  # Input GeoJSON file
#output_name_prefix = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # Output name prefix
#sdate = arcpy.GetParameter(3)  # Start date
#edate = arcpy.GetParameter(4)  # End date
#new = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)  # new parameter

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Testing Parameters
input_type = 'WFS Query'

sdate = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)
edate = datetime.now()
new = 'sample-filter-here'  # can be any type

output_prefix = 'test_out_'

if input_type == "File":
    pass
    #  If user passes a json/geojson file, do a straight conversion (this works fine)

elif input_type == "WFS Query":  # if user wants to do a query, construct url and make a call

    cql_filter = {
        'sdate': sdate,
        'edate': edate,
        'new': str(new),
    }

    q = wq.WFSQuery(get_url(), **cql_filter)

    print(q.kwargs)  # are params read in right?
    print(q.user_cql)  # are params being appended correctly?
    print(q.url)  # is the url being concatenated right?
```

The code above works correctly.  It spits out a URL with properly formatted CQL filter appended to it.

However, when I use arcpy.GetParameter() functions to set the variables, I get:

```
    q = wq.WFSQuery(get_gets_url(), **cql_filter)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sdate'
```

This is confusing.  When I use arcpy.AddMessage(cql_filter) to see if the **kwargs are the same as those I'm issuing in the test script (and of the same type), they appear to be.  The two dictionaries used as input are identical.  The arcpy script tool gathers the parameters correctly. The only difference between the test and the live script is that the GetParameter() function calls are uncommented (and other minor stuff like environment variables).  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Here is the "live" script as requested. I've stripped some of the ephemera from it (there are a ton of fields, also another custom import to build feature classes which works fine).

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import os
import wfs_query as wq


def get_url():
    json_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'config/servers.json')
    try:
        with open(json_file) as f:
        config_json = json.load(f)
        return config_json['server']
    except IOError:
        arcpy.AddError(f"Config file {json_file} was not found.")
    except ValueError:
        arcpy.AddError(f"Config file {json_file} is not valid json.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set environment variables
    current_project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
    current_db = current_project.defaultGeodatabase

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Fields
    field_list = [
        ['first', 'TEXT', 'First', 64],
        ['second', 'TEXT', 'Second', 32],
        ['third', 'TEXT', 'Third', 32]
    ]

    # Parameters
    input_type = arcpy.GetParameter(0)  # Choice of file or service call
    input_file = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # Input GeoJSON file
    output_name_prefix = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # Output name prefix
    start_date = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  # Start date
    end_date = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)  # End date
    new = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)  # new

    sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

    if input_type == "File":
        with open(input_file, 'r') as jf:
            gets_data = sp.SOMFeatures(current_db, output_name_prefix, field_list, sr, jf)
            parsed_gets_data = gets_data.parse_json()
            feature_classes = gets_data.make_features(parsed_gets_data)

        for fcs in feature_classes:
            arcpy.AddMessage(f"Created feature class {fcs['name']} with {fcs['rows']} rows.")
    elif input_type == "GETS WFS Query":

        cql_raw = {
            'sdate': start_date,
            'edate': end_date,
            'new': new,
        }

    q = wq.WFSQuery(get_url(), **cql_raw)
    arcpy.AddMessage(q.kwargs)
    arcpy.AddMessage(q.user_cql)
    arcpy.AddMessage(q.url)
```

Comment: Can you post the 'live' script as well?

Comment: @J.Flann No problem, just edited the question to show it at the bottom.  There's some unrelated stuff cut out, but this gets at the core of what's not working.

Comment: It's not clear why you're getting the error.  If the init function definition accepts **kwargs I dont see how you could get the unexpected keyword argument error.  There must be something missing here.

Comment: If you have a github user ID I could share the entire toolbox with you, including the validation code.

Comment: I am jflann on github

Comment: I would suggest adding a test routine in the script that fails.  Put the WFSQuery creation in a try/except and if it fails examine all the function arguments.  Then try to do the same thing with test arguments and see if that succeeds or fails.  Compare all of the arguments and see if you can identify the difference.